# How to improve a code for Tic Tac Toe-Check Victory in Python

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I am writing a python code for making a tic tac toe game.  I need to write a function that takes in three inputs, board, x, and y.  Board being the current display of the board and then x and y being values of 0, 1, or 2.  The game is set up to ask the user for coordinates.

```
def CheckVictory(board, x, y):

    #check if previous move was on vertical line and caused a win
    if board[0][y] == ('X') and board[1][y] == ('X') and board [2][y] == ('X'):
        return True
    if board[0][y] == ('O') and board[1][y] == ('O') and board [2][y] == ('O'):
        return True

    #check if previous move was on horizontal line and caused a win
    if board[x][0] == ('X') and board[x][1] == ('X') and board [x][2] == ('X'):
        return True
    if board[x][0] == ('O') and board[x][1] == ('O') and board [x][2] == ('O'):
        return True

    #check if previous move was on the main diagonal and caused a win
    if board[0][0] == ('X') and board[1][1] == ('X') and board [2][2] == ('X'):
        return True
    if board[0][0] == ('O') and board[1][1] == ('O') and board [2][2] == ('O'):
        return True
    #check if previous move was on the secondary diagonal and caused a win
    if board[0][2] == ('X') and board[1][1] == ('X') and board [2][0] == ('X'):
        return True
    if board[0][2] == ('O') and board[1][1] == ('O') and board [2][0] == ('O'):
        return True

    return False 
#end of CheckVictory function
```

the function is called in the game loop like so

```
p_x, p_y = playerTurn(board)    #let player take turn
displayBoard(board)             #show board after move has been made
if CheckVictory(board, p_x, p_y):   #see if user has won
    print("CONGRATULATIONS, you win!")
    newGame(board)  #game over start new one
    continue
```

and it's similar for the computer turn

I feel like there is a better way to write this function.  I feel like I should be using x and y more or there is a better way to check rather than writing all the possibilities. So what's a better way to write this? To make it short and concise.

Comment: If your code works, codereview.stackexchange.com is probably a better place to ask. (Although I'd check for existing questions about Python tic-tac-toe implementation first)

Comment: It works but then my later functions with this function in them will not work correctly because I think I wrote this function poorly.

Comment: 1. The function should not be aware of the last move. As you have access to `board` you can evaluate the current state to find out whether on party has won. 2. You could use for-loops to check whether there are 3 in a row horizontally or vertically. Now simply add checks for diagonals. 3. Pass the party you want to check as parameter (X or O)

Comment: @cah: StackOverflow is better suited for questions that have objective, definitive answers. How to "write a function better" is subjective. Do you want it to be faster? More maintainable? Less cohesive? These might be conflicting goals. I would recommend that you follow Wooble's advice about taking this to codereview, which is designed for exactly this type of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see why you need `x` and `y` parameters, you're supposed to check if there are three X letters or three O letters in a row, you don't need coordinates for that.
Instead edit the board first so it updates the coordinates player entered, then check if the victory happened.

Here's how I would do it, but if you want to use your method - feel free to. You can still learn something from my version.

```
def check_victory(board):
    combinations = [
        # horizontal
        ((0,0), (1,0), (2,0)),
        ((0,1), (1,1), (2,1)),
        ((0,2), (1,2), (2,2)),
        # vertical
        ((0,0), (0,1), (0,2)),
        ((1,0), (1,1), (1,2)),
        ((2,0), (2,1), (2,2)),
        # crossed
        ((0,0), (1,1), (2,2)),
        ((2,0), (1,1), (0,2))
    ]

    for coordinates in combinations:
        letters = [board[y][x] for x,y in coordinates]
        if len(set(letters)) == 1:
            return letters[0] # returns corresponding letter for winner (X/O)

    return False
```

Notice that it uses list comprehension and sets. If you're not familiar with those, I recommend to learn them before using this solution.